# Add new attribute to JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have JSON data and I want to update items on it.

How can I add a `name` attribute to ALL id's in controller ?

```
{ 
  "games" : [
      { "id":["1"] },
      { "id":["2"] },
      { "id":["3"] },
      { "id":["4"] },
      { "id":["5"] },
      { "id":["6"] }
   ]
}
```

Should be :

```
{ 
  "games" : [
      { "id":["1"],"name":"1" },
      { "id":["2"],"name":"2" },
      { "id":["3"],"name":"3" },
      { "id":["4"],"name":"4" },
      { "id":["5"],"name":"5" },
      { "id":["6"],"name":"6" }
   ]
}

for (var i = 1; i <= games.length; i++) {
    games[].name = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forEach` to loop through every items of the `data.games` array and  then simply add the `name` property using `game.name = game.id[0]`.

```js
const data = { 
  "games" : [
      { "id":["1"] },
      { "id":["2"] },
      { "id":["3"] },
      { "id":["4"] },
      { "id":["5"] },
      { "id":["6"] }
   ]
};

data.games.forEach(game => game.name = game.id[0]);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Good answer but maybe some comments to describe what is happening with `data.games`.